# Column in DataTable taking up too much space

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using a DataTable widget in my Flutter Web App to display some stuff. The problem is that when I reduce my screen width, the table is not adapting to it. I implemented this widget previously and it seemed to work perfectly. The widget makes the 2nd column overflow instead of reducing the space between the 1st and the 2nd column.

EDIT: Removing columnSpacing makes the DataTable take up the free space, but the Font Type text widget still overflows.

Is there any way I can fix this?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcGYz.png)

This my code:

```dart
void addRows() {
    searchRows = [];
    loadedFonts.forEach((font) {
      searchRows.add(DataRow(
        cells: [
          DataCell(Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              FontImage(font),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              Text(font.family),
            ],
          )),
          DataCell(Text(font.type)),
          DataCell(Text(font.weights.length.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(font.isPaid ? "No" : "Yes", style: TextStyle(color: font.isPaid ? Color(0xff9b475d) : Color(0xff447c69)),),),
        ],
        onSelectChanged: (value) {
          print(font.family);
        },
      ));
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      showCheckboxColumn: false,
      headingTextStyle: MyTheme.cardValue.copyWith(fontSize: 20),
      dataTextStyle: MyTheme.cardKey.copyWith(fontSize: 17, letterSpacing: 0.8),
      horizontalMargin: 0,
      dataRowHeight: 60.0,
      sortAscending: famSort,
      sortColumnIndex: 0,
      columnSpacing: 1,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Font Family"),
          onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
            sortByFamily(ascending);
          },
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Font Type"),
          onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
            sortByType();
          },
        ),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Weights")),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Free"),
          onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
            sortByPay();
          },
        ),
      ],
      rows: searchRows,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try to Increase your columnSpacing: 30, inside DataTable Widget

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering a big set of data then you can try with google charts api.

1. checkout the official documentation : ( https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table )
2. Combine with dart-js-web interoperability ( https://dart.dev/web/js-interop )

I hope this helps to answer your question. Share that how did you solved the issue.